# How I can path arguments from function to macro

Tags: rust

Explain, I have macro info!("Hello world") from [Rust log](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.5/log/)
And it works well anywhere, but not in common.rs file from [Organize test rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch11-03-test-organization.html) for cargo integration test. Because of macro use declaration (for import) must be declared in the root module and then provides for child modules. But in an integration test case, we don't have the root module and can't provide a macro for common.rs (child module).

Example 1:
Module parent 
mod.rs

```
#[macro_use]
use extern crate some_crate;

mod child.
```

in this case, the child can use macro without problem

Example 2:
No module (as integration test case), just test file 
some_test.rs

```
#[macro_use]
use extern crate some_crate;

mod child.
```

in this case, the child does not see macro, and we can provide macro use only this way.

For solving this problem I create a util module logger_util, which can use macro and then imported in some_test.rs

Example 3:
No module (as integration test case), just test file 
some_test.rs

```
 mod child
```

child.rs

```
use logger_util

fn foo() {
    logger_util.use_macro()
}
```

logger_util.rs

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate some_crate;

pub fn use_macro() {
    some_macro!("Hello world")
}
```

And my question is next:
How can I instead this:

```
fn foo() {
    info!("{} {} ", 123, "hello world")
}
```

Do this, from:

```
fn foo() {
    let print_data: SomeType = "{} {} ", 123, "hello world";
    use_macro(print_data)
}
```

To logger_util.rs

```
pub fn use_macro(print_data: SomeType) {
    info!("Hello world")
}
```

Comment: why not use `print_data = format!(...` ? What's the purpose of SomeType ?

Comment: It is utterly unclear what you're asking here, and as already mentioned, some pieces of your code are unknown. Please seek to make a proper [MCVE], and see if you can proofread the rest of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
use logger_util;  

fn foo() {
    logger_util::use_macro(format_args!("{} {} ", 123, "hello world"))
}

use std::fmt::Arguments;    

pub fn use_macro(args: Arguments) {
    info!("{}", args)
}
```